# Left back button not appearing

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display my view controller with a left back button. However, the button does not appear.

```
let vc = TermsAndConditionsViewController()
let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
vc.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navController.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
topViewController.present(navController, animated: true)
```

Edit 1: I use UINavigationDelegate without displaying the button yet.

```
extension HomeTabBarController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                              willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        var navigationBarHidden = true
        
        switch viewController {
        case is TermsAndConditionsViewController:
            navigationBarHidden = false
        default:
            navigationBarHidden = true
        }
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
        navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationBarHidden, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let vc = TermsAndConditionsViewController()
let btn = UIButton()
btn.setTitle("Title", for: .normal)
let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)
//vc.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navController.navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = item
navController.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
topViewController.present(navController, animated: true)
```

Comment: what is the customView?

Comment: It's using another initializer of UIBarButtonItem which create the item based on your custom view. Here I used a UIButton (btn) as the custom view. You can then add actions to the btn using addTarget method or do other customizations.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617151-init

Comment: Thank you for your resoponse but I do not use any custom view in this view controller

Comment: You do need too! It's just another way I creating UIBarButtonItem. Just test and run the code I wrote.

Comment: I tested it but it does not show the button.

Comment: I tested it with a regular UIViewController and it shows the left button correctly. Are you modifying the navigationController properties inside your TermsAndConditionsViewController?

Comment: Yes, inside the viewDidAppear:         self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false